# how to find lines in a ms word paragraph text using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

i am trying to fill the blanks a the end of lines of a paragraph by a char( - ) , and to do that i should find each line in the paragraph and i think to do that is by finding the carriage return  .but never worked any suggestion to find lines .

i've tried to do so finding by going through the paragraph text and look for one of these '\n' '\r' '\u000A' and count count how many of them but always got 0 
edit :
here some code :

```
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref oSaveAsFile, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
     ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
     ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
     ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        oWord.Visible = false;
        Word.Paragraph par = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs[2];
        string text = par.Range.Text;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            if (text[i] == '\u000a')
                j++;
        MessageBox.Show("line :" + j);
        oDoc.Close();
```

Comment: for example let us say we have a paragraph like this:   this is ttext this is      \n this is text this is text   so what i want is this :    this is text this is----  \n this is text this is text

Comment: @TatoTia: please edit your question and show us the C# code and not examples of your text.

Comment: TatoTia: the problem with this is recognizing the "end of the line" at the end of the paragraph. Please try something in the Word UI, as a user, to see if the approach works for your requirement: (in following comment)

Comment: 1) Click at the end of a paragraph. 2) Press TAB. 3) Open the "Paragraph" dialog box (the Dialog launcher in the Paragraph group of the Ribbon's Home tab). 4) Click the button "Tabs". 5) Set the tab position (the position of the right-hand margin of the page); Click the Option for a right-aligned tab stop; Click the tab character for `------`. 6) Click `Set` to dismiss the dialog box and add this tab stop. This should add dashes up to the tab stop position, which would be from the end of the paragraph to the end of the line. If the approach works, we can work on the necessary code.

Comment: Note: to find a paragraph use Word's built-in `Range.Find` feature with the `Find.Text = "`^p";` But that won't be the optimal approach if what's described above works for you...